# how to make dependent another dropdown for filter in angular

Tags: angular, forms, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms

how to make dependent another drop down for filter in angular.i have multiple drop down they depend on each other . i am using reactive form.

```
   <select (change)="checkFirstDropdown()" formControlName="id" class="FormControl cond-size">
                  <option value="null" disabled >Please Select Option</option>
                  <option [ngValue]="noneDropDown" selected>
                    none
                  </option>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="checkMainIndex==0">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let conditionsOperatorElement of allObjects.conditionsOperator">
                    <option *ngIf="conditionsOperatorElement.conditionsOperatorId==1"  [ngValue]="conditionsOperatorElement.conditionsOperatorId"
                    >{{
                      conditionsOperatorElement.title
                    }}</option>
                  </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngIf="checkMainIndex!=0">
                  <option  [ngValue]="conditionsOperatorElement.conditionsOperatorId"
                    *ngFor="let conditionsOperatorElement of allObjects.conditionsOperator">{{
                      conditionsOperatorElement.title
                    }}</option>
                </ng-container>
                </select>
```

Comment: If you think it was helpful then you can accept my answer.

Comment: I think there will be a tick mark to accept the answer.

Comment: best wishes.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. You can do that on your `change` function.
Here is my sample code and [stackblitz Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-select-option-7hnrv4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Reactive forms SELECT-OPTIONS</h1>
<h2>Tracking simple string</h2>
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <label>Country:</label><br>
    <select formControlName="country" (change)="checkFirstDropdown($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
            {{ country.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
     <br>  <br>
     <label>City</label><br>
     <select formControlName="city" >
        <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
            {{ city.city }}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {Country} from './country';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  countries = [
    {
      id: 'us',
      name: 'United States'
    },
    {
      id: 'uk',
      name: 'United Kingdom'
    },
    {
      id: 'ca',
      name: 'Canada'
    }
  ];

  cities=[];
  form = new FormGroup({
    country: new FormControl(),
    city: new FormControl()
  });
  
  checkFirstDropdown($event){
     this.cities=cityList.filter(c=>c.cid===$event);
      let  itm=this.cities[0];
      this.form.controls['city'].setValue(itm.id);
     console.log($event);
  }
}

export const cityList = [
  {
    id: "1",
    cid: 'ca',
    city: "toronto",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
     cid: 'ca',
    city: "Vancouver",
  
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    cid: 'us',
    city: "New York City",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
     cid: 'us',
    city: "Los Angeles",
  
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    cid: 'uk',
    city: "London",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    cid: 'uk',
    city: "BRIGHTON",
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        **HTML**:
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Select Category</label>
              <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" 
               (change)="onCategoryChange()"
                (change)="checkFirstDropdown(selectedCategory)">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category"> 
                 {{category}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
    
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Select Product</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="products">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product"> 
         {{product.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="Container">
            <app-my-table></app-my-table>
        </div>
    
    </div>

**TS**:
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
    import { Product } from '../product';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-pos',
      templateUrl: './pos.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./pos.component.css']
    
    })
    export class POSComponent implements OnInit {
      categories: string[] = [];
      products: Product[] = [];
      selectedCategory: string = '';
      selectedCategoryProducts: any[] = [];
    
      constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
        //it loads your first dropdown data
        this.loadData();
      }
      loadData() {
        this.productService.getCategoriesOnly().subscribe((category: any) => {
          this.categories = category.data;
        })
      }
      //checks first dropdown value 
      checkFirstDropdown(selectedCategory: string) {
        this.selectedCategoryProducts = this.products.filter(c => c.category === selectedCategory);
        if (selectedCategory != null || selectedCategory != "Select") {
          this.getProductByCategory(selectedCategory);
        }
      }
      // its an api call in service which gets data for 2nd list
      getProductByCategory(category: string) {
        this.productService.getProductByCategory(category).subscribe((product: any) => {
          this.products = product.data;
        })
      }
      // on changing category first it will empty the array of products
      onCategoryChange() {
        this.products = []; // Reset selected product when category changes
      }
    
    }
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).